# "no such index at level 1" error for a specific scenario when trying to use data.table programmatically

Tags: r, data.table, subset

### The Problem

I wrote a function to use data.table programmatically. The function is as follows

```
transformVariables4              <- function(df_1n_data,
                                             c_1n_variablesToTransform,
                                             c_1n_newVariableNames,
                                             f_01_functionToTransform,
                                             ...) {

  for (i in 1:length(c_1n_variablesToTransform)) {
    df_1n_data[, c(c_1n_newVariableNames[i]) := list(forceAndCall(n = 1, FUN = f_01_functionToTransform, df_1n_data[[c_1n_variablesToTransform[i]]], ...))]
  }

  return(df_1n_data)
}
```

The function works fine for this scenario

```
df <- data.frame(abcd = (as.Date("1991-12-22") + 1:10), e = 1, f = 2)
df4 <- transformVariables4(
  df_1n_data = data.table(df),
  c_1n_variablesToTransform = "e",
  c_1n_newVariableNames = "new",
  f_01_functionToTransform = sum,
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

But not for the below scenario

```
df <- data.frame(abcd = (as.Date("1991-12-22") + 1:10), e = 1, f = 2, g = 3, h = 4, i = 5, j = 6, k = 7, l = 8)
df4 <- transformVariables4(
  df_1n_data = data.table(df),
  c_1n_variablesToTransform = "e",
  c_1n_newVariableNames = "new",
  f_01_functionToTransform = sum,
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

It throws an error saying

> Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1

The only difference between the two scenarios is that in the second scenario the data contains more columns

I'm trying to figure out what the problem might be and fix it. It is taking a bit of time. **If there is some other way in which I can make this work quickly it'd be great :)**

---

### What I figured out so far

I tried debugging it. Below is a part of the traceback output

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1 

12 (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x, 
    i, exact = exact))(x, ..., exact = exact) 

11 `[[.data.frame`(df_1n_data, c_1n_variablesToTransform[i]) 

10 df_1n_data[[c_1n_variablesToTransform[i]]] 

9 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 

8 eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) 

7 `[.data.table`(df_1n_data, , `:=`(c(c_1n_newVariableNames[i]), 
    list(forceAndCall(n = 1, FUN = f_01_functionToTransform, 
        df_1n_data[[c_1n_variablesToTransform[i]]], ...)))) at abcd.R#75

6 df_1n_data[, `:=`(c(c_1n_newVariableNames[i]), list(forceAndCall(n = 1, 
    FUN = f_01_functionToTransform, df_1n_data[[c_1n_variablesToTransform[i]]], 
    ...)))] at abcd.R#75

5 transformVariables4(df_1n_data = data.table(df), c_1n_variablesToTransform = "e", 
    c_1n_newVariableNames = "new", f_01_functionToTransform = sum, 
    na.rm = TRUE) at abcd.R#90
```

The line of code at the top (indicated by `12`) is in the source code of the function `[[.data.frame`. The value of `i` in that line of code for the first scenario is

```
"e"
```

but for the second scenario it is

```
c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)
```

which is making `.subset2(x, i, exact = exact)` fail. Next step is to figure out the cause of this behavior.

**Update**

Figured out the cause of this behavior. It is because the `i` on the RHS of `:=` in

```
df_1n_data[, c(c_1n_newVariableNames[i]) := list(forceAndCall(n = 1, FUN = f_01_functionToTransform, df_1n_data[[c_1n_variablesToTransform[i]]], ...))]
  }
```

matches a column name in the data. Next step is to figure out why exactly this happened and what is the right way to go about doing this

**Update**

Thanks Roland for helping me understand why exactly this happened and what is the right way to go about doing this

The `i` issue is a scoping issue. data.table uses the first `i` on its search path which is the `i` column in the data which is all `NA`s and that in turn causes `.subset2` to fail. The right way to go about doing what I set out to do will be by using the second function from Roland's solution

Comment: @Roland Hi :) You can run the code for the function definition and the code for the scenario for which it didnt work. You should be getting the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would rewrite it like this:

```
transformVariables4              <- function(df_1n_data,
                                             c_1n_variablesToTransform,
                                             c_1n_newVariableNames,
                                             f_01_functionToTransform,
                                             ...) {

  for (i in seq_along(c_1n_variablesToTransform)) {
    var <- c_1n_variablesToTransform[i] #to force evaluation
    df_1n_data[, (c_1n_newVariableNames[i]) := f_01_functionToTransform(get(var), ...)]
  }

  df_1n_data[]
}
library(data.table)

df <- data.frame(abcd = (as.Date("1991-12-22") + 1:10), e = 1, f = 2, g = 3, h = 4, i = 5, j = 6, k = 7, l = 8)
df4 <- transformVariables4(
  df_1n_data = data.table(df),
  c_1n_variablesToTransform = "e",
  c_1n_newVariableNames = "new",
  f_01_functionToTransform = sum,
  na.rm = TRUE
)
```

Of course, more idiomatic would be this:

```
transformVariables4              <- function(df_1n_data,
                                             c_1n_variablesToTransform,
                                             c_1n_newVariableNames,
                                             f_01_functionToTransform,
                                             ...) {

  df_1n_data[, (c_1n_newVariableNames) := lapply(.SD, f_01_functionToTransform, ...), 
              .SDcols = c_1n_variablesToTransform]

  df_1n_data[]
}
```

I would also use shorter parameter names to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both functions work awesomely :)

I have two questions

1. Why the square brackets in `df_1n_data[]`?

2. For the function definition from the question, the problem seems to be because the `i` in the code matches a column name in the data. When I removed the `i` column from the data, it worked! Can you point me to some reading material so that I can better understand why this is happening?

Comment: 1) If you don't include this, the result is not printed first time you type `df4` in the console. This has been covered in the NEWS for one of the data.table version and can probably found in the documentation somewhere.

Comment: 2) That's a typical scoping issue. How is data.table supposed to know which `i` you meant? It uses the one found first on the search path.

Comment: 1) I noticed that the result wasn't getting printed on the console sometimes. I thought it was some random issue I'm facing :P Now I know it is not

2) Okayy. I could change the `i` to some exotic string so that it has a very less chance of being a column name. But, the second function in your solution doesn't even have a loop and is much more developer friendly :) I'll use that

Thank you :)

Comment: I'd second the "more idiomatic" one and the suggestion to shorten var names. Maybe a bit more idiomatic would be to add the trailing [] to the line before it. That's what I do, anyways.