# subset data.table by indexed column and rows continued

Tags: r, data.table

I am looking to subset a data table recursively, by changing the index of the column z AND at the same time filter rows based on some `%in%` based vector.

As a **continuation** of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187338/subset-data-table-by-indexed-column-and-rows) successfully answered by @akrun I am receiving the following error when I run an adaptation of the code below. `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds`

```
dt <- setDT(copy(diamonds))
dt <- setDT(data.frame(lapply(dt, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
z=4
subset_by <-  unique(dt[[z]])
i1 <- dt[, .I[.SD[[1]] %in% subset_by], .SDcols = z]
dt[i1]
```

The way I addressed the issue is by adjusting the filtering part to the following, which if you run this for the existing `dt` you will get error `Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : no such index at level 1` whereas it works for me.

```
dt<- dt[dt[[z]] %in% subset_by]
```

However, I would like to understand why the original did not work and the latter does. The error tells me that the `second` subset fails because I am selecting it as out of bounds. It might be useful to highlight that I am using it deeply nested in a complex Shiny app

Comment: Might be related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37480543/no-such-index-at-level-1-error-for-a-specific-scenario-when-trying-to-use-data

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. You first example doesn't make sense because `i1` will always contain all row numbers. What is the expected result? `dt<- dt[dt[[z]] %in% subset_by]` gives the error you describe which is likely a scoping issue since `z` is taken from within the data.table and not from the global environment.

Comment: As @Roland mentioned, the `z` is not getting accessed `dt[dt[[get("z", envir = .GlobalEnv)]] %in% subset_by]`

Comment: As the goal has always been to recursively filter the `dt`, `z` is externally obtained by default. However, in my case, `z` is not in the global environment, and it should not be, as the creation and filtering of the `dt` happens 5 "levels" deep within the shiny app.